# PHP Phone Number Replace Regex

Tags: php, regex

I have a regex pattern I found for removing phone numbers from strings of text. It works great, except a couple of cases (these are US phone numbers).

Here is the regex:

```
/\(?\d{3}\)?[-\s.]?\d{3}[-\s.]\d{4}/x
```

Here are the cases I need to catch:

- 55555555555 (area code + 7 numbers)
- 155555555555 (1 + area code + 7 numbers)
- (555)-5555555 (area code in parenthesis, dash, 7 numbers)
- 1-555-555-5555
- 1-(555)-555-5555

Here is the regex replace I am using:

```
$pattern = "/\(?\d{3}\)?[-\s.]?\d{3}[-\s.]\d{4}/x";
$replacement = "[phone redacted]";
$body = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $body);
```

Comment: Your examples certainly don't cover every way people could try to get around this redaction scheme, so I hope it's truly representative of your data :)

Comment: Yes, its hard because people entering phone numbers in a text area is unpredictable. It's difficult to say, well, is 55555555 a price, or a phone number?

Comment: erg edit: but in this case, I know exactly the text being edited, so the matches here should almost always be a phone number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
/(?:1-?)?(?:\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})[-\s.]?\d{3}[-\s.]?\d{4}/
```

**test:**

```
$arr = array(
'5555555555 (area code + 7 numbers)',
'15555555555 (1 + area code + 7 numbers)',
'(555)-5555555 (area code in parenthesis, dash, 7 numbers)',
'1-555-555-5555',
'1-(555)-555-5555');

$pattern = "/(?:1-?)?(?:\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})[-\s.]?\d{3}[-\s.]?\d{4}/x";
$replacement = "[phone redacted]";
foreach($arr as $body) {
  echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $body), "\n";
}
```

**output:**

```
[phone redacted] (area code + 7 numbers)
[phone redacted] (1 + area code + 7 numbers)
[phone redacted] (area code in parenthesis, dash, 7 numbers)
[phone redacted]
[phone redacted]
```

Comment: +1 looks pretty good - catches more cases than asked for, but HOPEFULLY that won't be a problem :)

Comment: Gave this a +1 but would like to add the use of periods, such as: 1.555.555.5555 which is growing in popularity.

Comment: @Abela: It works also with period and space see `[-\s.]` except for the first one, just replace `(?:1-?)?` with `(?:1[-.]?)?`

Answer (score 0):

This one should match:

```
(1-?)?(-?\([0-9]{3}\)|[0-9]{3})(-?[0-9]{3}){2}[0-9]
```

Comment: This actually replaced everything (no text at all).

Comment: When I have a paragraph that has 1-555-555-5555 etc in it, it finds it, but also removes all text. Updating original question.